# Identifying derived class from base class

Tags: c++, pointers, polymorphism, virtual, abstract

Is there any way to check if two instances are the same derived class? Something like:

```
Base *inst1 = new A();
Base *inst2 = new B();
Base *inst3 = new A();


bool b1 =  (inst1->class== inst2->class); //<-- should evaluate to false
bool b1 =  (inst2->class== inst3->class); //<-- should evaluate to true
```

Obviously I could just add a virtual function to the base class and implement each derived class to return a unique value. However, I would prefer not having to implement anything specific for the derived class as I am making an API based around deriving from this base class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
typeid(*inst1) == typeid(*inst2)
```

assuming that `Base` has at least one virtual function. Otherwise, typeid won't be able to get the right derived type.

Comment: Just to be clear, there's also no way to distinguish between a base class and it's derived class (without doing unsafe casts) if there are no virtual functions, so you probably wouldn't care about that caveat anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a method that returns the class from which the instance is derived. However, dynamic_cast can be used to check if the instance is compatible with a specific Class.

A& inst_ans = dynamic_cast(inst2); 
will throw an exception

where as
A& inst_ans = dynamic_cast(inst1); 
will execute properly

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_cast